# Does method overload work with exception types?

Tags: c#, exception, overloading

```
using System;

// Custom Exception types
class AException : Exception
{
}

class BException : Exception
{
}

class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new AException();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Callme(ex);
        }
    }
    public static void Callme(AException aexception) {}
    public static void Callme(BException bexception) {}
    public static void Callme(Exception ex) {}
}
```

`Callme(ex)` will always call `Callme(Exception ex)` instead of `Callme(AException ..)`  .. Is this an expected behavior. I read method overload resolution do work with inheritance relationships.

Comment: Yes, because you catch the exception as the base `Exception` class type.  Overload only works when you have a reference type that matches the more specific type.

Answer (score 2):

there is a more accepted way of doing this. try the following:

```
        try
        {
            throw new AException();
        }
        catch (AException aex)
        {
            Callme(aex);
        }
        catch (BException bex)
        {
            Callme(bex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Callme(ex);
        }
```

Comment: so the idea is too have a catch for each of you handled Exception Types - leave the most generic one to last though (important)

Comment: I know this works, But my question is why the original code snippet does not work.

Comment: i believe it is due to error being caught as type `Exception`